# Translucent blue inspection indicator generated by chrome dev tools needs styling

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a pseudo selector for this item? I am talking about the milky blue rect that appears on elements being inspected. It is too obtrusive and I would like to change it to just an inset `box-shadow` with an animated hue-rotation.

I suspect it lives in the shadow dom somewhere, what techniques could be employed to sniff it out minesweeper style?

The context is from a chrome extension.